# Crawl the first paragraph link in wiki

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup, python-requests

how to crawl the first paragraph link in wiki?

All the links in the parentheses should be excluded. As an example i provide the follow link:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data.

On this page the first link i want to crawl is "**qualitative**" *(href="/wiki/Qualitative_property")*. My code has excluded all the special links like footnotes and pronunciation but can't exclude the normal link in the parentheses.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
response = requests.get('https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data')
html = response.text
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")
link = soup.find(id='mw-content-text').find(class_="mw-parser-output").find_all('p', recursive=False)
list_a = []
for element in link:
    if element.find("a", recursive=False):
        print(element.find("a", recursive=False).get('href'))
        break
```

Comment: I think I fixed your problem. Take a look at my answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, technically speaking, those links are not different from the links outside the parentheses. If you look closer at the *href* attribute of those links, all of them begin with */wiki/Help:* so, you can leave them out if that happens. In the code below I used *regular expressions* for doing that:

#### Code

```
import re
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
response = requests.get('https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data')
html = response.text
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")
paragraphs = soup.find(id='mw-content-text').find(class_="mw-parser-output").find_all('p', recursive=False)
list_a = []

# Help links RegEx
help_link_regex = re.compile('^/wiki/Help:')

for p in paragraphs:
    p_links = p.find_all("a", recursive=False)

    for link in p_links:
        # Leave them out if they match the previous RegEx
        if not help_link_regex.match(link.get('href')):
            print(link.get('href'))
            list_a.append(link.get('href'))
            break
```

#### Output

```
/wiki/Qualitative_property
/wiki/Information
/wiki/Measurement
/wiki/Data_(word)
/wiki/Information
/wiki/Knowledge
/wiki/Sign
/wiki/Marketing
/wiki/Analog_computer
/wiki/Johanna_Drucker
```

Note the first link in this list is the first link (outside parentheses) in the first paragraph: the link you wanted.

The previous code just adds the **first non-help link of each paragraph** to `list_a`, if you want to get them all, just remove the `break`:

#### Output (after removing the `break`)

```
/wiki/Qualitative_property
/wiki/Quantitative_data
/wiki/Variable_(research)
/wiki/Information
/wiki/Scientific_research
/wiki/Stock_price
/wiki/Crime_rate
/wiki/Unemployment_rate
/wiki/Literacy
/wiki/Homelessness
/wiki/Measurement
/wiki/Data_reporting
/wiki/Data_analysis
/wiki/Data_visualization
/wiki/Concept
/wiki/Information
/wiki/Knowledge
/wiki/Data_processing
/wiki/Number
/wiki/Character_(computing)
/wiki/Outlier
/wiki/Field_work
/wiki/In_situ
/wiki/Experimental_data
/wiki/Petroleum
/wiki/Digital_economy
/wiki/Data_(word)
/wiki/Mass_noun
/wiki/Information
/wiki/Knowledge
/wiki/Wisdom
/wiki/Shannon_entropy
/wiki/Knowledge
/wiki/Mount_Everest
/wiki/Altimeter
/wiki/Sign
/wiki/Marketing
/wiki/Social_services
/wiki/Truth
/wiki/Analog_computer
/wiki/Computer
/wiki/Alphabet
/wiki/Computer_program
/wiki/Lisp_(programming_language)
/wiki/Metadata
/wiki/Johanna_Drucker
```

I hope this helps you, otherwise, let me know what went wrong.

Comment: @joe please, let me know if this works for you. If so, mark my answer as **accepted** (green checkmark) and upvote it. Thanks in advance